# Apache Pulsar connection refused

Tags: apache-pulsar

In my Pulsar consumer/producer, when trying to connect to Pulsar, I'm getting this error message:

> java.util.concurrent.CompletionException:
>   org.apache.pulsar.client.api.PulsarClientException:
>   java.util.concurrent.CompletionException:
>   org.apache.pulsar.shade.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException:
>   syscall:getsockopt(..) failed: Connection refused:
>   pulsar-ms-tls.mydomain.com/10.16.60.179:6652

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to reach the wrong port. Pulsar, by default, uses port 6651. Please verify that you're using the correct port (based on how your Pulsar cluster has been configured).

It's also possible that your IP address is incorrect, so be sure to double-check that you're hitting an IP address that's running a broker instance.